# How to prove a sequence is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series

For a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 1}$, let a sequence $\{y_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be defined by the formula $$y_n = \dfrac{x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n}n \ \forall n\in \Bbb{N}$$

Prove that if the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is bounded, then so is $\{y_n\}_{n\ge 1}$. (Recall that a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is bounded if there exists a positive real number $M$ such that $|x_n| < M$ $\forall n\in \Bbb{N}$ )

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. While posting a question, please include your ideas and whatever approach you've taken up, so that users can identify your doubts and their help can be more focused in clearing your doubts since this is not a homework solving site. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Here's a hint: Try to prove that if a $M$ (in the definition for boundedness) works for the $x_n$ sequence, it works for $y_n$ too.

Comment: More interesting is: if {$y_n$} is bounded, then is {$x_n$} bounded? And the answer seems to be: no, not necessarily.

Comment: I agree with the previous comments and also advise trying specific examples.  For example, suppose $10$ is an upper bound for $\{x_n\}.$  Is there any way that **any** element $y_n$ can ever exceed $10$?

Answer (score 3):

Because $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}, \ |x_i| < M$, then
$$\left|\dfrac{x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n}n\right| \leqslant\frac{|x_1| + |x_2| + \ldots + |x_n|}{n} \leqslant\frac{M+M+\cdots+M}{n}=\frac{Mn}{n}=M$$

Comment: how can it go from < to Mn? Like how come M can just be multiplied by n?

Comment: @Mather. Change each $|x_i|$ accordingly $|x_i| < M$ and note, that you have $n$ summands.

Answer (score 0):

For every $n, x_n \in (-M,M)$, so the average of the first $n$ elements of {$x_n$} will also be in $(-M,M)$